# Place to insert an abbreviation

Tags: writing-style, abbreviations

When I put an abbreviation for the first time in a document, is this better if I insert it right after the corresponding spelled out name?

For example, is ex1. better than ex2.?:

> > ex1. The engineer team should  establish an management system (hereinafter “MS”) in accordance with xxx.
> >
> > ex2. The engineer team should  establish an management system in accordance with xxx (hereinafter “MS”).

Comment: This depends to a degree on the publication's established "style", but I mostly see "management system (MS)", with no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put it right after the name, for more clarity! The "hereinafter" is fine but maybe not necessary.